# json element is not displaying

Tags: javascript, express, nodes, ejs

i am a newbie to ejs,and i have input tag like this

```
<input class="form-control" id="inputName" type="text" <% { %>value='<%= JSON.stringify(result.firstname) %>'<% } %>
```

here, the printing data is empty.

but if i give the value like :

```
<input class="form-control" id="inputName" type="text" <% { %>value='<%= JSON.stringify(result) %>'<% } %>
```

it prints the whole JSON data like this

```
[{"userid":526,"firstname":"asdw","lastname":null,"username":"aasdasd","password":"sadadsadsadasda","email":"asdasf.m@asd.com","contact":null}]
```

what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your json Object is an array, try this: `JSON.stringify(result[0].firstname)`.

To return a json Object which is not an array, maybe you should do some modifications at your back end.